# Load multiple views dynamically on single page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I am developing a windows 8 application using Html5 and javascript. Is it possible to load multiple html pages on one html page, depending upon certain condition?

usecase is I have vertical tabs or section on one page. Clicking on vertical tab shows a view on the same page and on tap there will be multiple tabs to navigate.

one way of designing the same might be defining all the views as different div and changing the visibility as per requirement. Looking for more optimized or accepted solution.

New to this technology so please share links or explain in detail.

Comment: You can use [`$(container).load(HTML-file)`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), then later clear the HTML in the selected container with [`$(container).html('')`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did that using **iframe** tag

```
  <iframe id="navigation-data-source" src="/TEMPLATES/navigationTemplate.html"></iframe>
```

you can have multiple iframe on page to insert multiple htmls. to access any control first we get the particular frame with id and dig it more to update any control inside html.